# using multi-threading to excute member function

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to use python to code a multi-threading program. Since I am very new to python, I appologise if I asked something common to you.

Here is my code in main:

```
multi_threads = []
simulator = Simulation(simulation_number)
    # Simulation is my class, run() is a member function

for i in range(0, thread_number):
    multi_threads.append(Thread(target = simulator.run, args = (start, end,)))

for i in range(0, thread_number):
    multi_threads[i].start()
    multi_threads[i].join()
```

and in `Simulation::un`:

```
def run(self, start, end):
    # do something...
    print "in run"
    return
```

I expect to see `in run` few times. But it turns out there is nothing.

May I know what am I wrong?

Comment: you should call 'start' method.http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start

Comment: @danihp Yes I called `start` and `join` for each of the threads.

Comment: You should do it in two loops, first one to starts and wecond one to joins. Avoiid do both operations in single loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some complete code:

```
from threading import Thread

class Simulation(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        pass

    def run(self, start, end):
        print "Running",start,end

simulation_number=None

start = None
end = None

thread_number=5


multi_threads = []
simulator = Simulation(simulation_number)
# Simulation is my class, run() is a member function


for i in range(0, thread_number):
    multi_threads.append(Thread(target = simulator.run, args = (i, end,)))

for i in range(0, thread_number):
    multi_threads[i].start()
    multi_threads[i].join()
```

And that does output "Running" for each thread - although in this case each thread runs to completion before the next one is started, so there's no point using threads.

Comment: Just a note here that the `args=` param on the `Thread()` constructor should be a list, not a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.start()` on the thread. So in your case:

```
for t in multi_threads:
    t.start()
```

**Edited to change run to start (thanks to commenters, I misremembered the method name)**

Comment: you mean `start` it isn't?

Comment: Note that calling `run` you are *not* running the code concurrently, it's just a regular method call. You must use `start`, which will execute the `run` method on a different thread.